# Thread troubles and drawing line on view

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to draw a line with this code but on the image view I can't see a picture. If I call only `paintComponent()` it works very well. I can see two lines but if I call `startDrawing()`, I get the error below. At first, I tried without `new Canvas()` and `setImageView()` but theres nothing to do.

**LogCat:**

```
07-21 04:41:43.489: W/System.err(1770): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    07-21 04:41:43.529: W/System.err(1770):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
    07-21 04:41:43.529: W/System.err(1770):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:857)
    07-21 04:41:43.529: W/System.err(1770):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4320)
    07-21 04:41:43.549: W/System.err(1770):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10935)
    07-21 04:41:43.569: W/System.err(1770):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10890)
    07-21 04:41:43.569: W/System.err(1770):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:426)
    07-21 04:41:43.569: W/System.err(1770):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageView.java:439)
    07-21 04:41:43.569: W/System.err(1770):     at graphing.GraphPanel.run(GraphPanel.java:577)
    07-21 04:41:43.569: W/System.err(1770):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)*
```

**There is code:**

```
    public class GraphPanel  implements Runnable  {



    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8880798842884968375L;
    private double minX = -10;
    private double maxX = 10;
    private double minY = -10;
    private double maxY = 10;
    private double xInterval;
    private double yInterval;
    private int xAxis = 0;
    private int yAxis = 0;
    private int panelHeight = 0;
    private int panelWidth = 0;
    private boolean firstResize = true;
    private static Vector<Equation> equations = new Vector<Equation>();
    private static Vector<Path> polylines = new Vector<Path>();
    private Vector<Thread> threads = new Vector<Thread>();
    private boolean stopThreads = false;
    private boolean painting = false;
    private int currentEq = 0;
    private static HashMap<String, PointF> points = new HashMap<String, PointF>();
    SurfaceView view;
    private Canvas g2;
    private Paint p;


    ImageView imageview;
    Bitmap bitmap;




    public GraphPanel(ImageView imageview, int width, int height) {


        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( width,height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        p=new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.imageview=imageview;

    }



    private void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }


    public void paintComponent() {
        painting = true;
        g2 = new Canvas(bitmap);
           imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        yAxis = UnitToPixelX(0);
        xAxis = UnitToPixelY(0);
   //    GraphSettings.setDrawGrid(true);
        // Draw Grid
        if (GraphSettings.isDrawGrid()) {
            //g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            xInterval = Math.pow(10, String.valueOf((int) (maxX - minX) / 4).length() - 1);
            yInterval = Math.pow(10, String.valueOf((int) (maxY - minY) / 4).length() - 1);

            xInterval = yInterval = Math.min(xInterval, yInterval);

            for (double i = 0 + xInterval; i <= maxX; i += xInterval) {

                g2.drawLine(UnitToPixelX(i), 0, UnitToPixelX(i), g2.getHeight(),p);
            }
            for (double i = 0 - xInterval; i >= minX; i -= xInterval) {
                g2.drawLine(UnitToPixelX(i), 0, UnitToPixelX(i),  g2.getHeight(),p);
            }
            for (double i = 0 + yInterval; i <= maxY; i += yInterval) {
                g2.drawLine(0, UnitToPixelY(i), g2.getWidth(), UnitToPixelY(i),p);
            }
            for (double i = 0 - yInterval; i >= minY; i -= yInterval) {
                g2.drawLine(0, UnitToPixelY(i), g2.getWidth(), UnitToPixelY(i),p);
            }
        }


        // Draw crossheir
        g2.drawLine(g2.getWidth() / 2 - 5, g2.getHeight() / 2, g2.getWidth() / 2 + 5, g2.getHeight() / 2,p);
        g2.drawLine(g2.getWidth() / 2, g2.getHeight() / 2 - 5, g2.getWidth() / 2, g2.getHeight() / 2 + 5,p);

        // Draw x and y axis
        g2.drawLine(0, xAxis, g2.getWidth(), xAxis,p);
        g2.drawLine(yAxis, 0, yAxis, g2.getHeight(),p);

        painting=false;
    }



    private synchronized void increasePolylineNumber(int eqNumber) {
        while (polylines.size() < eqNumber + 1) {
            polylines.add(new Path());
        }
    }

    public void startDrawing() {
        stopThreads = true;
        for (Thread t : threads) {
            t.stop(); //TODO: Terbile design. This should be changed later. But it works for testing.
        }
        threads.clear();
        polylines.clear();
        stopThreads = false;
    //  .draw(g2);

    //  repaint();

        for (int i=0; i<equations.size(); i++) {
            threads.add(new Thread(this));
            threads.lastElement().start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            g2=new Canvas(bitmap);
              imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //  imageview.setI
            int eqNumber = this.getNextEQ();
            Equation eq = equations.get(eqNumber);

            increasePolylineNumber(eqNumber);
            Path polyline = new Path();/*(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, this.getWidth());*/

            boolean firstPoint = true;
            double interval, intervalFormula, slope;
            Double eqVal;
            Double eqPrev = 0.0;
            String expr = eq.getExpression();

            // Set values for loop.
            try {
                eqPrev = Equation.evaluate(expr, minX, false);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                equations.clear();
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Argument.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            int unittopixelxmin=UnitToPixelX(minX),
                    unittopixelxeqprev= UnitToPixelY(eqPrev);

            polyline.moveTo(unittopixelxmin,unittopixelxeqprev);
            // Printer.print("\neqNumber:" + eqNumber);
            // Printer.print("Size:" + polylines.size());
            polylines.set(eqNumber, polyline);
            interval = intervalFormula = (maxX - minX) / (bitmap.getWidth());
           int xtest=0,ytest=0;
            // Start loop.
            int loop = 0;
            for (double x = minX;; x += interval) {
                if (stopThreads) {
                    break;
                }

                // eqVal and pixValX are used a lot. Solve only once.
                eqVal = Equation.evaluate(expr, x, false);
                int pixValX = UnitToPixelX(x);

                if (eqVal.isNaN() || eqVal.isInfinite()) {
                    firstPoint = true;
                } else if (firstPoint) {
                    polyline.moveTo(pixValX, UnitToPixelY(eqVal));
                    polylines.set(eqNumber, polyline);
                     xtest=pixValX;
                     ytest=UnitToPixelY(eqVal);
                    firstPoint = false;
                } else {
                    polyline.lineTo(pixValX, UnitToPixelY(eqVal));
                    polylines.set(eqNumber, polyline);
                     xtest=pixValX;
                     ytest=UnitToPixelY(eqVal);
                }

                // Set interval.
                slope = Math.abs((eqVal - eqPrev) / (x - (x - interval)));
                if (slope > GraphSettings.getMinCalcPerPixel()) {
                    if (slope > GraphSettings.getMaxCalcPerPixel()) {
                        slope = GraphSettings.getMaxCalcPerPixel();
                    }
                    interval = intervalFormula / slope;
                } else {
                    interval = intervalFormula;
                }
                eqPrev = eqVal;

                if ((loop++ % 10 == 0 || x >= maxX) && !painting) {


                    p.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2.drawLine(0,0,120,120, p);    
                //  repaint();

                    //g2.drawPath(polyline, p); 
                //  view.draw(g2);

                }
                if (x >= maxX) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            p.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.drawLine(0,0,120,120, p);    
            p.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.drawLine(unittopixelxmin,unittopixelxeqprev, xtest, ytest, p);

            System.out.print(polylines);
            System.out.print(polyline);
              // imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        /*  for(Path path:polylines){
            Log.e(path.toString(), path.toString()) ;
            g2.drawPath(path, p);
            }*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```